# get the object matched with value provided in the json object using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object which looks like this and i have and random parameters for "skus" value in my json object

like

```
     var mytestvalue="Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120)"; or
      var mytestvalue="Color:Coyote (120),Fit:Regular"; 


     [
       {
            "index":0,
        "title":"Foo1",
        "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:6,Color:Coyote (120)",
   },
   {
        "index":1,
        "title":"Foo2",
        "skus":"Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120),Size:65",
   },
   {
        "index":2,
        "title":"Foo3",
        "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:7,Color:Coyote (120)",
   },
   {
        "index":0,
        "title":"Foo4",
        "skus":"Color:Coyote (120),Fit:Regular,Size:7.5",
       },
       {
        "index":1,
        "title":"Foo5",
        "skus":"Fit:Slim,Size:8,Color:Coyote (120)",
       },
   {
        "index":2,
        "title":"Foo6",
        "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:9,Color:Coyote (120)",
   },
   { 
        "index":0,
        "title":"Foo7",
        "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:8.5,Color:Coyote (120)",
  },
  {
        "index":1,
        "title":"Foo8",
        "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:10,Color:Coyote (120)",
 },
 {
        "index":2,
    "title":"Foo9",
        "skus":"Fit:Slim,Color:Coyote (120),Size:13",
 },
 {
        "index":0,
        "title":"Foo10",
        "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:8.5,Color:Coyote (120)",
 },
{
        "index":1,
        "title":"Foo11",
        "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:10,Color:Coyote (120)",
},
{
        "index":2,
        "title":"Foo12",
        "skus":"Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120),Size:13",
}
    ]
```

i wrote a function to get the matched combinations of skus with variable i have

```
   function getSkuCombinations(obj,prodskuval) {
     var combres = $.grep(obj, function (o) { //Will give you all the matches
            return o.SKUOptions.indexOf(prodskuval) > -1;
     });
     return combres;
}
```

i call this function like this

```
     var combinationresults=getSkuCombinations(myobj,mytestvalue)
```

when i do this i should get all the skus which have the combination "mytestvalue" which i passed but this function now only returns me

```
       var myresult= [{
                "index":1,
                "title":"Foo2",
                "skus":"Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120),Size:65",
                  }]
```

can any one help me in doing this

this function solved my problem,

```
     function getSkuCombinations(obj,prodskuval) {
          var combres = $.grep(obj, function (o) { //Will give you all the matches
                var newskus=o.skus.split(',').sort().join(',');             
                var newprdskus=prodskuval.split(',').sort().join(',');             
                    return newskus.indexOf(newprdskus) > -1;
         });
    }
```

Comment: Your function getSkuCombinations not return nothing. Must be return combres?

Comment: Yes i forgot to addit here yes it returns the combres

Comment: @Jhonathan i changed that,can you check this now

Comment: @Jhonathan thank you for showing a way to solve my issue,  was able to solve this with solution provided by the jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method which solved my problem

```
function getSkuCombinations(obj,prodskuval) {
      var combres = $.grep(obj, function (o) { //Will give you all the matches
            var newskus=o.skus.split(',').sort().join(',');             
            var newprdskus=prodskuval.split(',').sort().join(',');             
                return newskus.indexOf(newprdskus) > -1;
     });
}
```

Comment: Well, if you articulated you wanted the matching to be made based on the quasi-attributes (`name:value` separated by `,` as part of a plain String) to be matched against the `skus` from array elements regardless of the order of those quasi-attributes, then maybe someone would have thought of that, too.
Regardless of our wasted efforts, here's the advice: refactor the quasi-attribute String (`mytestvalue`) to an actual Object and then change the `getSkuCombinations()` to work with it as such. That way someone other than you will make some sense from the code later on :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var mytestvalue="Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120)"; or
      var mytestvalue="Color:Coyote (120),Fit:Regular";     

var myobj = [
           {
                "index":0,
            "title":"Foo1",
            "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:6,Color:Coyote (120)",
       },
       {
            "index":1,
            "title":"Foo2",
            "skus":"Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120),Size:65",
       },
       {
            "index":2,
            "title":"Foo3",
            "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:7,Color:Coyote (120)",
       },
       {
            "index":0,
            "title":"Foo4",
            "skus":"Color:Coyote (120),Fit:Regular,Size:7.5",
           },
           {
            "index":1,
            "title":"Foo5",
            "skus":"Fit:Slim,Size:8,Color:Coyote (120)",
           },
       {
            "index":2,
            "title":"Foo6",
            "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:9,Color:Coyote (120)",
       },
       { 
            "index":0,
            "title":"Foo7",
            "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:8.5,Color:Coyote (120)",
      },
      {
            "index":1,
            "title":"Foo8",
            "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:10,Color:Coyote (120)",
     },
     {
            "index":2,
        "title":"Foo9",
            "skus":"Fit:Slim,Color:Coyote (120),Size:13",
     },
     {
            "index":0,
            "title":"Foo10",
            "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:8.5,Color:Coyote (120)",
     },
    {
            "index":1,
            "title":"Foo11",
            "skus":"Fit:Regular,Size:10,Color:Coyote (120)",
    },
    {
            "index":2,
            "title":"Foo12",
            "skus":"Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120),Size:13",
    }
      ]
```

This is you new function:

```
function getSkuCombinations(obj, prodskuval) {
         var combres = $.grep(obj, function (o) { //Will give you all the matches
                        return o.skus.split(',').sort().toString() == prodskuval.split(',').sort().toString();
                 });
         return combres;
}
```

Is necessary that function getSkuCombinations consider both case :

```
var mytestvalue="Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120)"; or
var mytestvalue="Color:Coyote (120),Fit:Regular";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkSKU = function (obj, testValue) {
    var results = [];
    obj.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.skus.indexOf(testValue) > -1) {
            results.push(item);
        }
    });
    return results;
};
```

JSFiddle test case: http://jsfiddle.net/N9V9q/3/

Comment: this is returning all the objects , i mean the same object again

Comment: Either be clearer with your question or start upvoting.  This solves the problem you've presented.

Comment: there are objects with different fit, which shouldn't be as i specified

Comment: Updated, just for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

function getSkuCombinations(obj,prodskuval) {
         var combres = $.each(obj, function (key, value) { //Will give you all the matches
                return val.skus.indexOf(prodskuval) > -1;
         });
    }

Comment: This option not consider distinct order in characteristic of skus

Answer (score 0):

Tested it with Node.js. If you change `SKUOptions` (dunno waht that is) to `skus` (attribute of the object in the `myobj` JSON), then it works:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

var mytestvalue = "Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120)";
// var mytestvalue = "Color:Coyote (120),Fit:Regular";

var myobj = [{
  "index": 0,
  "title": "Foo1",
  "skus": "Fit:Regular,Size:6,Color:Coyote (120)",
}, {
  "index": 1,
  "title": "Foo2",
  "skus": "Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120),Size:65",
}, {
  "index": 2,
  "title": "Foo3",
  "skus": "Fit:Regular,Size:7,Color:Coyote (120)",
}, {
  "index": 0,
  "title": "Foo4",
  "skus": "Color:Coyote (120),Fit:Regular,Size:7.5",
}, {
  "index": 1,
  "title": "Foo5",
  "skus": "Fit:Slim,Size:8,Color:Coyote (120)",
}, {
  "index": 2,
  "title": "Foo6",
  "skus": "Fit:Regular,Size:9,Color:Coyote (120)",
}, {
  "index": 0,
  "title": "Foo7",
  "skus": "Fit:Regular,Size:8.5,Color:Coyote (120)",
}, {
  "index": 1,
  "title": "Foo8",
  "skus": "Fit:Regular,Size:10,Color:Coyote (120)",
}, {
  "index": 2,
  "title": "Foo9",
  "skus": "Fit:Slim,Color:Coyote (120),Size:13",
}, {
  "index": 0,
  "title": "Foo10",
  "skus": "Fit:Regular,Size:8.5,Color:Coyote (120)",
}, {
  "index": 1,
  "title": "Foo11",
  "skus": "Fit:Regular,Size:10,Color:Coyote (120)",
}, {
  "index": 2,
  "title": "Foo12",
  "skus": "Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120),Size:13",
}];

function getSkuCombinations(obj, prodskuval) {
  var combres = $.grep(obj, function(o) { //Will give you all the matches
    return o.skus.indexOf(prodskuval) > -1;
  });
  return combres;
}

var combinationresults = getSkuCombinations(myobj, mytestvalue)
console.log(combinationresults);
```

Returns:

```
[ { index: 1,
    title: 'Foo2',
    skus: 'Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120),Size:65' },
  { index: 2,
    title: 'Foo12',
    skus: 'Fit:Regular,Color:Coyote (120),Size:13' } ]
```

**jsFiddle** *(look for console.log)*: http://jsfiddle.net/Saran/Y8wwE/

Comment: This option not consider distinct order in characteristic of skus in comparision

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what SKUOptions is. Can you paste that part of your code?